# image path using asset in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have a stored path in my database. Now I want to show images according to the path stored in the database. This works well with HTML and Laravel. But when appending using Javascript, the path is incorrect.(js file is in public folder).asset() and url() function of laravel will not parse in html as they are of blade page.

```
<div id="diFproD">
    @php $index=0; @endphp @for($i=0;$i < count($productDetails);)
        <div class="row">
            @for($j=0;$j < 4; $j++)
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-5 thumb">
                    <a class="thumbnail"
                       href="{{url('/product/macchi-product-sapCode-'.$productDetails[$i]['ProductName'].'-'.$productDetails[$i]['ProductId'])}}"
                       style="box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 3px #337ab724">
                        <img src="{{asset($productDetails[$i]['ProductPath'])}}" class="img-rounded"/>
                        <p>Para 1 Test 1</p>
                        <p>Para 1 Test 1</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
                @php $i++;if($i == count($productDetails)){ break; } @endphp
            @endfor
        </div>
    @endfor
</div>
```

Tried a few things.

```
var cntProd = data.length;
$('#diFproD').empty();
var rowDivPro = '';
for (var i = 0; i < cntProd;) {
    rowDivPro += '<div class="row">';
    for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        var prodId = data[i].ProductId;
        var prodWeit = data[i].ProductWeight;
        var prodName = data[i].ProductName;
        var prodPath = data[i].ProductPath;
        var custLoc = '{{ url("/product/macchi-product-sapCode-" }}';
        rowDivPro += '<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-5 thumb">';
        rowDivPro += "<a class='thumbnail' href='"
            + custLoc
            + prodId
            + "' style='box-shadow:0px 1px 3px 3px #337ab724'>";
        rowDivPro += '<img src="{{url(' + prodPath
                                + ')}}" class="img-rounded">';
        rowDivPro += '<p>Para 1 Test 1</p><p>Para 1 Test 1</p>';
        rowDivPro += '</a>';
        rowDivPro += '</div>';
        i++;
        if (i == cntProd) {
            break;
        }
    }
    rowDivPro += '</div>';
}
$('#diFproD').append(rowDivPro);
```

How do I set the `src` for image and `href` for anchor tag in javascript
where href is path to route

image path is like `localhost:8080/MyProject/public/{{url(/IMAGES/image.png)}}`
it should be like this instead `localhost:8080/MyProject/public/IMAGES/image.png`

Comment: Your `<a class='thumbnail` is not closed. Whats the value of `prodPath`?

Comment: I think you are mixing frontend and backend. The `url()` function is laravel function(*i think*) and you are concatenating it in javascript variable `prodPath`?

Comment: i know url i used with laravel but i need something like that in javascript so that i can get image path from database and display the image that is stored in the folder.Is there any way around.Also not able to call the route using anchor tag

Comment: And is a `prodPath` javascript variable. What is the example value of `prodPath` ?

Comment: eddie..prodid and product path are from database. The problem is i am not getting the proper path both in anchor tag href and image src

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
    var prodPath = '"'+{{url("'"+data[i].ProductPath+"'")}}+'"';
```

and

```
rowDivPro += '<img src="'+prodPath+'" class="img-rounded">';
```

Comment: brother its not php variable it is javascript variable

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: already tried this.Not Obtain Valid Path. my js file is in public folder and images are also in public folder

Comment: what is the value of prodPath and url(prodPath)

Comment: src="IMAGES/images.png".see my laravel blade code i want same thing using javascript

Comment: Edited the answer again

Comment: it will be one and the same thing.please read the last two line of my question

Comment: last attempt try that one

Comment: url () and asset will not parse the same way as they parse in laravel blade page.so provide me any other alternative